# Kubernetes helm Java API

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8, kubernetes-helm

Is there any known Java API to use Kubernetes helm (something like the great KubernetesClient from fabric8)? I am trying to initial helm commands from Java but I couldn't find anything that actually works...

Thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 9):

I've written [microbean-helm](https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm).  This project:

1. Checks out the `.proto` files from the Helm project…
2. …generates their gRPC Java bindings…
3. …and adds a couple of utility classes.

The end result is that Tiller, the server-side component of Helm that does all the heavy lifting like chart installation, etc., is addressable and drivable from Java.  I am guessing that that is what you really want.

You may follow along at its [Github repository](https://microbean.github.io/microbean-helm/).

Comment: Does not support Helm v3 and development is sadly extremely slow, right now.

Answer (score 6):

we've not created a Java API for helm yet on the fabric8 team.

The simplest thing is probably to just use the `helm` binary for now from your $PATH (or from a docker container if you're using Jenkins Pipeline).

BTW the fabric8 maven plugin supports generating helm charts: https://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:helm

You can then apply the helm chart via the command line:

```
mvn install
helm install target/fabric8/helm/kubernetes/myapp
```

Comment: It's deprecated?!

Comment: Hey @james-strachan, is there a helm3 client in fabric8?